# Timed execution of bash script fails when conda environment changes

Tags: python, bash, cron, conda, environment

I have a workflow using an R script and Python scripts that is controlled from shell scripts.

The workflow uses 5 different conda environments (geo_env, pygmt, image, wbt, earthpy). A shell script was necessary to change the environments on the fly so that the workflow can be automated, e.g.

conda deactivate
conda activate pygmt
python "script_1.py" $regions

conda deactivate
conda activate geo_env
python "script_2.py" $regions

~/.bashrc modified so a source command is not be needed. Here is the relevant section of ~/.bash.rc

## >>> conda initialize >>>

## !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!

__conda_setup="$('/home/smcc/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
eval "$__conda_setup"
else
if [ -f "/home/smcc/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
. "/home/smcc/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
else
export PATH="/home/smcc/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
fi
fi
unset __conda_setup

## <<< conda initialize <<<

## smcc edit to permit conda activate to work in a shell script

export -f conda
export -f __conda_activate
export -f __conda_reactivate
export -f __conda_hashr
export -f __conda_exe

## end smcc edit

---

It works very well. The problem arises when I execute the initial shell script using either crontab or at. In both cases, the run fails at the first environment change. Can someone suggest how to fix this, please?

It works very well. The problem arises when I execute the initial shell script using either crontab or at. In both cases, the run fails at the first environment change. Can someone suggest how to fix this, please?

Comment: Use `conda run` instead.

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely tidier. The workflow still runs fine from the command line using 'conda run -n environment_name python python_script' to set environments in my shell script. Unfortunately, cron is still not executing the shell script as expected. It still seems to hang at the first conda run command. I wonder if my edits to ~/.bash.rc (above) are confusing things now I'm using conda run.

Comment: Yeah, I don’t believe edits should be necessary. Is there a shebang on the shell script?

Comment: Yes, there is: #!/bin/bash right at the start of the file. I'll try commented out those edits that I made to the ~/.bash.rc file.

Comment: Typically, I use `#!/usr/bin/env bash -l` for my scripts (loads user profile), but not sure that's appropriate for a cronjob.